# Запятые после "что" — не могу найти правила

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в примерах (когда при устной речи после "что (же)" делается более менее длительная пауза)?

1. А что, мы никуда не поедем?
2. Ну что, поехали!
3. — Он что, (так) похож на своего брата?
   — Получается, так. / Выходит, да. / Получается, похож.
4. — Так что же, у неё два мужа?
   — Выходит, два (у Ульяны Андреевны, жены Буншы).
5. Так что, он теперь, значит, депутат?
6. Что, вы так и ни разу не были на Таити?
7. Ты что, не знаешь, как расставить запятые в данных примерах ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все запятые расставлены верно.

[Правило](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131#pp131)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! По поводу 7-го примера. Значит, даже если после Я, Ты, Он, Мы и других местоимений и личных имен идет слово "что", и оно разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое, после него все рано ставится запятая ? Например: Ты что, спортсмен, что ли? Он что, совсем плохой, что ли ? Они что, совсем ничего не знают? Но ведь здесь получается, что запятая разрывает подлежащее со сказуемым. Мне тоже кажется, что запятые нужны, но я не могу найти конкретного правила.

Comment: Угрюм, в седьмом предложении запятые нужны. Но в некоторых случаях возможны варианты.    Ср.: Ты что же не идёшь с нами? — ‘почему?’

Ты что же, не идёшь с нами? — ‘что делаешь?’ с паузой после что же