# «Ты что, не видишь, что...» Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Ты что, не видишь, что двери заколочены или подперты?!*
Верно ли стоят запятые в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем предложении запятые расставлены верно.
Руководствуемся правилом Розенталя:

> **1.** Слова ***что, а что, что же***, обозначающие вопросы, и слова ***как, как же, что же***, выражающие удивление, подтверждение, согласие и т. п., за которыми следует предложение, раскрывающее их конкретный смысл (после них делается *пауза*), отделяются запятой: ***Что**, если я кликну клич?* (Т.) — ‘что будет, если…’; ***Что**, если в самом деле он* [городничий] *потащит меня в тюрьму?* (Т.); ***Что**, ему лет двадцать пять, не больше?* (Л. Т.); ***А что**, если он прячется в глубине лесов?* (Каз.)...

Они сказали китайскому царю: «**Ты что, не видишь, что** Сталин тебя обманывает. [Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема (Книга 1) (1989)]
― Сержант, **ты что, не видишь, что** перед тобой полковник? [Даниил Корецкий. Менты не ангелы, но… (2011)]
**Ты что, не видишь, что** форточка открыта? [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Понедельник начинается в субботу (1964)]

[Вопросительно-восклицательные слова](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131#pp131)

Answer (score 1):

Да верно.
По поводу запятой после "Ты что" можете посмотреть тут:
[Запятые после "что" — не могу найти правила](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417208/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0)